# Is it possible to create a query for this matter?

Tags: json, postgresql, api, get

Let's say I have an API that constantly gets updated. Basically I get it from a site and it's in json format. But instead of using the usual GET & POST method, I'd like to know if its possible to get it using postgresql.

What I'm trying to do is create a daily routine which will run a function using pgadmin to update the tables in the server based on the json data from the API. So it runs automatically daily without needing manual input.

So is it possible to create a GET method or something similar in the form of a query? Or are there other methods to approach this kind or matter? Basically getting the json data using the API automatically daily.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all, can you clarify?

Comment: Example: "example.com/user.json" . Based on this example link, how do I get the json data using postgreqsql query? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is possible, but it's not really the ideal use-case for SQL.

You could use [this](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) from within your Postgres query to make GET and POST requests to the site, and you will get JSON returned as a string which you could store in a JSON field. If you are unable to install extensions to your Postgres database, I don't believe there's anything built into Postgres to make HTTP requests.

You could use some [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) to parse the information out of the JSON payload, but they can't preform any complex logic by themselves, so you might create a pretty large query trying to parse large amounts of data.

Finally, to schedule the query on a daily basis, you could use [`pgAgent`](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html). This as well requires an additional installation since it isn't built into Postgres already.

I say that it might not be a good idea, since you should probably keep a separation between a data store and application logic, since this isn't the kind of thing that Postgres was designed to do. It would be much easier to capture and manipulate the data using a simple script or application that connects to the Postgres database, as well as the site website supplying the data. There are languages that are much better suited for handling this sort of situation, which would be much more legible and easier to maintain than a massive SQL query.

If you provide some more information about the specific scenario for why you're doing this, I could try to give you a more specific and insightful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Basically I have tables for an ecommerce database and the prices for each item have to be updated usually according to the currency rate. I don't want to make daily changes to the currency rates so I'm thinking of a way to update the currency rate tables automatically daily.

Comment: If that's the case, I would highly recommend making a small script that you automatically run on a daily basis. It will be much easier to read and maintain in the long term. If you are going to do it in SQL, I don't have enough specific knowledge about these tools to help, so you may have to post a second question if you run into more trouble.